# TI mobile and html/css

Tags: android, mobile, titanium

I am not sure about this and googling is not giving me a clear answer. I hope TI developers can enlighten me.

> Can I use my HTML and CSS  skills in
>   developing Titanium Mobile
>   application? Or Javascript is the only
>   way to develop using Titanium Mobile.

I want to use HTML and CSS in controlling my UI...

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titanium provides Javascript bindings for native controls and generally doesn't use HTML and CSS for layout. However, there's nothing keeping you from using web views inside your app for the visuals.

You might want to check out PhoneGap as an alternative if you really want to use web techniques for UI in addition to logic: http://www.phonegap.com/

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I did study phonegap and installed it in my device but I find it slow.